# Less than Greater than Keys enumeration in C#

Tags: .net, winforms

I've been searching to find out the values for < and > under `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`, but I can only find `OemOpenBrackets` and `OemCloseBrackets`. Could someone please help me?

Comment: .NET is really large; if you are talking about a specific class, fully qualify it.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong, use the KeyPress event instead of KeyDown/Up.

Not every keyboard layout in the world is the same as yours. On a German or [French keyboard](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdfr.html) for example, < is produced by an extra key next to the left Shift key, > by holding Shift and pressing that key.  Only the KeyPress event is reliable to correctly detect the keystroke.

Comment: +1 This is a better solution than using the key code from a key down event.

Answer (score 2):

The [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration defines virtual key codes, and there aren't ones for angle brackets. Angle brackets can appear on different keys for different keyboard layouts, so there is not *easy* reliable way to convert a virtual keycode to a character.

A better option is to use the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event (as suggested by [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19331111/177018)), and compare the `KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar` property directly with the `'<'` or `'>'` characters.

```
    private void MyKeyPressHandler(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '<')
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yippee");
        }
    }
```

If for some reason you are forced to use the key code from a KeyDown event, then your code will not work for different keyboard layouts.

For example, on my keyboard the < and > are on the comma and period keys, I could use `Oemcomma` and `OemPeriod`, in conjunction with `Shift`:

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma && e.Shift)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Works for certain keyboards.");
        }
```

Comment: It has to be in the form of 'if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma && Keys.Shift)' but it doesn't allow for two values for e.keycode. Should i just make another if statement inside the first?

Comment: @Mercifies I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It throws error saying && cannot be applied to operands of type bool

Comment: I think you probably something want something like `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma && e.Shift) ...`

Comment: he is looking for `if (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Oemcomma | Keys.Shift))`, i think?

Comment: No, wouldn't that apply the or operator? I need both to be pressed at the same time to enable the code. <---Came from Java sorry if I'm wrong about this

Comment: @Mercifies, in binary 001 | 100 = 101 if you compare to that it means that both bits are set. the Keys enum is similar (it's a Flags enum).

Comment: I've checked and the code in my comment is correct. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this with a WPF control, you'll need to use the PreviewTextInput event. I discovered this trying to get a '[' on a French keyboard.

```
private void OnRichTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("text = " + e.Text);
   Debug.WriteLine("sys txt = " + e.SystemText);
   if (e.Text == "<") { /* do something */ }
}
```

Sean